# How does Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm work with Priority Queues?

Tags: priority-queue, dijkstra

I have been reading online websites and everybody says that using a priority queue will make it good, but I don't understand what is used as the "priority" here.

At the very beginning, is the first item on the priority queue always the starting point node? If so, when we extract the starting node with distance 0, how do we get its neighbors from the priority queue?

Answer (score 2):

A priority queue `Q` stores a set of distinct elements. Each element
`x` has an associated key `x.key`

When Dijkstra is based on a priority queue. Then we store the vertices In the queue whose distances from the source are yet to be settled, keyed on their current distance from the source.

[image]
Take a look at this pdf where the algorithm is based on the abstract data structure called a priority queue, which can be implemented using a binary heap.

http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~montanar/teaching/dsa/dijkstra-handout.pdf